# Coalesce or otherwise fire methods "every so often"?

Tags: ios

The server that provides data to my app recently added a feature that allows you do to basic logging like "user selected logo" or "user is quitting".

The only place I'd like to use this is in a page with several sliders that does a  calculation on the input values. This is continuous, it re-calculates the output as you move the sliders around.

Which leaves me the problem of *when* to call this logging method. I don't want to call it every time the numbers change, or I'll murder the server. I could put a "Calculate now" button, but that kills the entire mode-less UI I like.

Is there a way that I can coalesce calls so all the calls made within, say, 5 seconds, results in only one call to the work method? I'd also have to force the method to fire if the user does something else, like navigates away or quits the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily add an `NSTimer` to the IBAction method you have for your slider. Every time that method is called, invalidate the timer and start it again. Put the analytics call in the timer's action method, which will only be called when the timer can actually complete.

For example:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSTimer *actionTimer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender 
{
    [self.actionTimer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"Slider value: %f", sender.value);
    self.actionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(timerCompleted) 
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timerCompleted
{
    NSLog(@"Timer completed.");
}

@end
```

Comment: I think this will work. Will the timer "go away" if the user leaves the page? Or do I need to do something to kill off any remaining outstanding timer events?

Comment: The timer will retain the view controller until it fires (provided that `sliderChanged:` has been called at least once). This technique typically works very well. I finally packaged it up into a reusable bit if you want: https://github.com/rnapier/RNCoalesce With this object, the view controller can deallocate, but the RNCoalesce will hang around until it fires.

Comment: Right, which now I realize is actually what I want in your solution, because that ensures that last event fires even if they move away within that 2 second window. And to ensure that I get at least one call, I'll do the actiontimer on WillActivate to start things off.

Comment: FYI, I implemented this with a 5-second timer and it works amazing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

How about a background thread that observes the calculated value and fires an update by scheduling a block on a background thread when the output value is stable, like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(showValue:)
                                             name:@"showValue"
                                           object:nil];
```

You can also schedule the block in `viewWillDisappear` for the leaving the view and (I think) quit events.